# Не получается распарсить json содержащий словарь

Tags: python, json

Есть задача распарсить json'ы [вот этот](http://services.tsi.lv/schedule/api/service.asmx/GetLocalizedEvents?from=1513548000&to=1513734400&teachers=&rooms=&groups=1308&lang=%27ru%27):

```
({"d":"{\"events\":{\"keys\":[\"time\",\"room\",\"groups\",\"teacher\",\"name\",\"comment\",\"class\"],\"values\":[[1513593000,[71],[1308],9713,\"Архитектура вычислительных систем\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513599300,[71],[1308],15653,\"Высшая математика\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513673100,[71],[1308],15728,\"Охрана труда, гражданская оборона и охрана окружающей среды\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513679400,[74],[1308],15651,\"Иностранный язык\",\"\",\"normal\"]]}}"})
```

или вот [такой](http://services.tsi.lv/schedule/api/service.asmx/GetLocalizedEvents?from=1513548000&to=1513634400&teachers=&rooms=&groups=1308&lang=%27ru%27):

```
({"d":"{\"events\":{\"keys\":[\"time\",\"room\",\"groups\",\"teacher\",\"name\",\"comment\",\"class\"],\"values\":[[1513593000,[71],[1308],9713,\"Архитектура вычислительных систем\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513599300,[71],[1308],15653,\"Высшая математика\",\"\",\"normal\"]]}}"})
```

В итоге нужно получить в отдельных переменных названия пар(name), время (time), аудиторию (room), и имя преподавателя (teacher). В том виде как они записаны в json. Количество пар может быть разное.

Comment: Лучше примеры тех json добавьте данных в вопрос, через кнопку `править`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перешел по ссылке и посмотрел на данные. Ошибка парсинга json была из-за круглых скобок, поэтому нужно от них избавиться (`text[1:-1]`), чтобы парсинг прошел успешно:

```
import json

text = r'({"d":"{\"events\":{\"keys\":[\"time\",\"room\",\"groups\",\"teacher\",\"name\",\"comment\",\"class\"],\"values\":[[1513593000,[71],[1308],9713,\"Архитектура вычислительных систем\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513599300,[71],[1308],15653,\"Высшая математика\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513673100,[71],[1308],15728,\"Охрана труда, гражданская оборона и охрана окружающей среды\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513679400,[74],[1308],15651,\"Иностранный язык\",\"\",\"normal\"]]}}"})'

data = json.loads(text[1:-1])
print(data)
```

---

Теперь нужно протестировать с сетью:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'http://services.tsi.lv/schedule/api/service.asmx/GetLocalizedEvents?from=1513548000&to=1513734400&teachers=&rooms=&groups=1308&lang=%27ru%27'

rs = requests.get(url)
text = rs.text

data = json.loads(text[1:-1])
print(data)
```

---

Заметил, что те данные соответствуют синтаксису контейнеров в [python](/questions/tagged/python), а значит можно сделать хитрый парсинг используя модуль [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) (но стоит помнить, что в [json](/questions/tagged/json) `false`/`true` и `null`, а в [python](/questions/tagged/python) это будет `False`/`True` и `None`, и такое расхождение вызовет ошибку при `ast.literal_eval`):

```
import ast

text = r'({"d":"{\"events\":{\"keys\":[\"time\",\"room\",\"groups\",\"teacher\",\"name\",\"comment\",\"class\"],\"values\":[[1513593000,[71],[1308],9713,\"Архитектура вычислительных систем\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513599300,[71],[1308],15653,\"Высшая математика\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513673100,[71],[1308],15728,\"Охрана труда, гражданская оборона и охрана окружающей среды\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513679400,[74],[1308],15651,\"Иностранный язык\",\"\",\"normal\"]]}}"})'

data = ast.literal_eval(text)
print(data)
```

Comment: @NickWynther, `ast.literal_eval(ast.literal_eval(text).get('d')).get('events')` ну а дальше либо сами либо [укажите в вопросе пример выходных данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/759638/edit), чтобы было понятно что вам нужно...